# Can Nativescript apps decompress zip files?

Tags: android, ios, zip, unzip, nativescript

This is a pretty simple question.

I'm developing a Nativescript App and need to decompress a zip file that will be downloaded to the phone's storage. Does anyone know how this can be acheived?

I've checked the Nativescript documentation but have not been able to find anything on decompressing zip files. In addition, I've tried a third-party plugin (the only one I could find) but the documentation is sparse and it doesn't seem to work (https://github.com/mobilemindtec/nativescript-background-task).

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking as well. Found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-zip

Install:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-zip
```